# How to print out elements of 2d vector vertically in c++?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a simple vector of vectors of integers.
The output of the below code will be

```
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8
9 10 11
```

I am trying to figure out how to get

```
1 6 9
2 7 10
3 8 11
4
5
```

```
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    vector<vector<int>> a  { {1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {9,10,11} };
      for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++ ) {
            
            cout << a[i][j] << " " ;
            
        }

        cout << endl;   
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: You only need to change two characters in your code, can you figure out which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line: `cout << a[i][j] << " " ;`, you just need to swap `i` and `j`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef> // for std::size_t
#include <algorithm>
// using namespace std; is bad, so don't use it.
int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a  {{1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {9,10,11}};
    std::size_t biggestSize{0};

    for(const auto &i : a) 
    {
        if(biggestSize < i.size())
        {
            biggestSize = i.size();
        }
    }
    for (std::size_t i {0}; i < biggestSize; ++i) // size() returns a std::size_t type
    {
        for (std::size_t j {0}; j < a.size(); ++j) //use postfix increment opreator instead of prefix
        {
             if(i >= a[j].size())
             {
                 std::cout << "  ";
             }
             else
             {
                 std::cout << a[j][i] << ' ' ; // swap i and j
             }
        }
        std::cout << '\n'; //use newline character instead of std::endl  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I get a segmentation error. It's because vector a in my program is { { 1, 2, 3}, { 4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, {13,14} }. Any thoughts. Simply swapping i with j does not work.

Comment: @YasiruLelwala I have updated my code for the following. Tell me if there's any bug.

Comment: `for(auto &i : a) biggestSize = std::max(biggestSize, i.size();` There's a missing `)`  at this line.

Comment: @justANewbie I ran your amended code (also included the change by Linux Geek) and tested it on the vector a { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9,10,11} }. I still get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @YasiruLelwala Sorry for that typo. I think that I fixed it now.

Comment: @YasiruLelwala Did you copied all the code from this answer?

Answer (score 0):

In line 13 just swap `I` with `J`:

```
cout << a[j][i] << " ";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I get a segmentation error. It's because vector a in my program is { { 1, 2, 3}, { 4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, {13,14} }. Any thoughts. Simply swapping i with j does not work.